# need to display all the terms for a given index

Tags: java, search, lucene, full-text-search

I need to display all the terms for a given Lucene index.

```
    public void addDocuments(IndexWriter indexWriter) throws IOException {
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    doc1.add(new TextField("title", "harrypotter", Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc1);

    Document doc2 = new Document();
    doc2.add(new TextField("title", "luceneinaction", Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc2);

    Document doc3 = new Document();
    doc3.add(new TextField("title", "harrypotter", Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc3);
}
```

I am trying this:

```
    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
    Terms terms = fields.terms("title");
    TermsEnum iterator = terms.iterator(null);          
    BytesRef byteRef = null;
    while((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) {
        System.out.println(byteRef.utf8ToString());
    }
```

However this gives me only unique terms:

```
harrypotter
luceneinaction
```

Is there anyway to get all the terms (duplicate as well)? Or terms are always unique?

Thanks.

PS: Lucene version is 4.0.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the main issue. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will give you the unique terms. However, you can get the count of the documents containing the term in the following way:

```
while ((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) {
    System.out.println(byteRef.utf8ToString() + " - " + iterator.docFreq());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), so it stores the references to terms like this:

```
harrypotter -> doc1, doc3
luceneinaction -> doc2
```

Each term points to documents as you can see above.

If you need to get terms for each document, run them separately through desired analyzer.